# Why is an array in my mongoose model preventing me from querying

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose model

```
 CartSchema = new Schema({
  company: String,
  items: [{
    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    price: Number,
    gears: [String]
   }],
 });
```

I access it via this simpe query

```
const response = await Cart.findOne( { "items": { _id: "5e4d7a5bcff77131f46d8aa9" } });
```

And this is my data in the mongo database

[image]

So from this information we can see that the only information that I have in my database that corresponds to the model is the `items[0]._id` which should be found with the query above. The odd thing is it returns null as long as this line `gears: [String],` is in my model. It is not required (I also tried setting it manually to `required : false` but I can't seem to get my data if this line is in my model. If I remove the line from my model, I can get the data just fine.

Am I missing something obvious here that would prevent me from getting my data because of the `gears: [String]` line in my model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by this way, `{ "items": { _id: "5e4d7a5bcff77131f46d8aa9" } }`, you're searching for an exact match, the `items` should be an `object` contains only the specified `_id`

instead, you should use the `dot notation` to filter by the `_id` in the `items` array

```
const response = await Cart.findOne( { "items._id": "5e4d7a5bcff77131f46d8aa9" });
```

hope it helps

Comment: I really thought I tried this in my research up to this point but it is working now thanks for your input !